# Possible to change the DWM aero tint color on a per-window basis?

Tags: winapi, aero

Is it possible to set the aero tint color on a per-window basis?
If so, what is the Win32 function to do this?

Comment: How wondrful for you.  I happen to be both a programmer and an end user, so my question is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no per-window tint.